# Why regex Matcher.find not showing a word which meets the criteria

Tags: java, regex, string

The given regex code is

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String longString = " Derek Banas CA 12345 PA (412)555-1212 johnsmith@hotmail.com 412-555-1234 412 555-1234 "; 
        regexChecker("\\s[A-Za-z]{2,20}\\s", longString);
    }

    public static void regexChecker(String theRegex, String str2Check){
        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);     
        Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher( str2Check );
        while ( regexMatcher.find() ){
            if (regexMatcher.group().length() != 0){
                System.out.println( regexMatcher.group().trim() );
                System.out.println( "Start Index: " + regexMatcher.start());
                System.out.println( "Start Index: " + regexMatcher.end());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output here is

```
Derek
Start Index: 0
Start Index: 7
CA
Start Index: 12
Start Index: 16
PA
Start Index: 21
Start Index: 25
```

1> Why is the output of Derek is 'end index 7' and not 6?

 2> Why isn't 'Banas' a part of the output?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need concrete help, please ask a concrete question. Also, I think my solution is just what you need because the second regex returns the matches without spaces, and still checks for whitespace boundaries (thus, returning just 2 to 20-letter words).

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern includes whitespace after the non-whitespace. That accounts for *both* of your questions: the space between "Derek" and "Banas" counts as part of the first match, which stops it being part of a match for "Banas" (because you'd need another space before "Banas" to match).

If you change both `\\s` to `\\b` it will match a word boundary - which doesn't use the space. You then get output of:

```
Derek
Start Index: 1
Start Index: 6
Banas
Start Index: 7
Start Index: 12
CA
Start Index: 13
Start Index: 15
PA
Start Index: 22
Start Index: 24
johnsmith
Start Index: 39
Start Index: 48
hotmail
Start Index: 49
Start Index: 56
com
Start Index: 57
Start Index: 60
```

At that point you're probably getting matches you don't want though.

You could continue to capture the whitespace at the front, but remove the one at the end. A pattern like this:

```
regexChecker("\\s[A-Za-z]{2,20}", longString);
```

gives output of:

```
Derek
Start Index: 0
Start Index: 6
Banas
Start Index: 6
Start Index: 12
CA
Start Index: 12
Start Index: 15
PA
Start Index: 21
Start Index: 24
johnsmith
Start Index: 38
Start Index: 48
```

Comment: Is there any other method I can use to find 'Banas' and all other possible matches?

Comment: Well it's not really clear what you're after. to be honest.

Comment: Initially, I wanted the list of all possible matches with \\s[A-Za-z]{2,20}\\s.
But it was not returning Banas in that case.

Comment: @user2769790: And I've explained why. But until you show what output you'd consider correct, we're not going to be able to help any more than we already have.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern matches a whitespace, 2 to 20 ASCII letters *and a whitespace* after. That means that the end of the first match is the space after `Derek`, that is the 7th index.

That also accounts for the fact `Banas` does not match: the first match already consumed the space before `Banas`, and the first `\s` does not match `B`, thus, `Banas` is skipped.

You need to make the last `\s` non-consuming, use

```
"\\s[A-Za-z]{2,20}(?!\\S)"
                 ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD8F58/1).

The `(?!\S)` negative lookahead matches a location in string that is immediately followed with either a whitespace or end of string. Note you may also use a similar "trick" with the first `\s` if you turn it into a `(?<!\S)` lookbehind, `"(?<!\\S)[A-Za-z]{2,20}(?!\\S)"`. Then, no whitespace will land inside the match value.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD8F58/2).

Another way to solve the issue is by using `\b` word boundaries that are also zero-width assertions, `"\\b[A-Za-z]{2,20}\\b"`.